# Magento 2: How can I overwrite Zend_Validate_Hostname class

Tags: magento2, email, zend-framework

How can I overwrite zendframework1/library/Zend/validate/Zend_Validate_Hostname class?

I need to overwrite to add hostnames in

> $_validTlds

The reason is the following error:

> "Email" no es un nombre de host válido.
> 'sfr.fr ' parece ser un nombre de host DNS, pero no podemos coincidir con el esquema de nombre de host para TLD 'fr '.
> 'sfr.fr ' no parece ser un nombre válido de red local.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like an easier solution is this

Modify Magento 2 `composer.json`

Here is an example of a file I've overwritten

```
"autoload": {
    [...]
    ,
    "files": [
        [...],
        "lib/Zend/Http/Response.php"
    ]
},
```

Copy the `vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Http/Response.php` to `lib/Zend/Http/Response.php`

Then run `composer dump-autoload`

Warning: You are overriding entire class. But this might suit your need.